# How do I shorten this liquid code?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to update the "New Order Notification" mail for my Shopify store with custom HTML code, but while pasting the code it simply doesn't paste 100% of it. I've contacted Shopify and they've told me there is no character limit but a file size limit of 64 or 128 kb.

The store has 18 main categories (collections). What I'm trying to do is make sure the products get sorted based on category name.

The following piece of code appears 18 times (for every category) in the custom template:

```
{% if verse_kantenklaar_maaltijden_salades != blank %}
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h2 style="margin-bottom:15px;margin-top:5px!important;font-weight:bold;">Verse kant-en-klaar maaltijden - salades</h2>
    </td>
  </tr>

  {% for line_item_id in verse_kantenklaar_maaltijden_salades %}
      {% for line_item in line_items %}
          {% capture line_item_string %}{{line_item.id}}{% endcapture %}
          {% if line_item_id == line_item_string %}

            {% assign bonus = 'no' %}

            {% for tag in line_item.product.tags %}
              {% if tag == 'Bonus' %}
                {% assign bonus = 'yes' %}
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

            <tr>
              <td>
                <a href="{{ line_item.product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'master' }}"><img alt="" src="{{ line_item.product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'large' }}" style="width: 400px;"></a>
              </td>

              <td style="text-align:left;">{{ line_item.title }} ({{ line_item.product.metafields.global.item_size }})<br>
                  <span style="font-size:34px;font-weight:bold;">
                    {% if bonus == 'yes' %}
                      {{ line_item.product.metafields.global.wpob | round: 2 }}
                    {% else %}
                      {{ line_item.product.metafields.global.wpo | round: 2 }}
                    {% endif %}
                  </span>

                  {% if bonus == 'yes' %}
                    <span style="font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;">BONUS</span>
                  {% endif %}

                  {% if line_item.quantity > 1 %}<span class="item_count" style="display: block;position: relative;width: 50px;text-align: center;background-color: #d14836;color: white;font-weight: 700;min-width: 80px;line-height: 40px;border-radius: 50px;">{{ line_item.quantity }}</span>{% endif %}
              </td>
            </tr>

          {%endif%}
      {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

For the full code (with 3 categories) take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/narzero/3f33087227f055401406).

Is there a way to simplify (using loops) or compress this to make sure the total template stays within Shopify limits?

Or might this be caused by something else? The total code length is around 1500 lines.

Comment: This is code review, and, therefore, off-topic for this site.

Comment: If you trim the leading whitespace, the gist you posted goes from ~5kb to ~4kb.  If you have it copied 18 times, that's 18k saved.

Comment: @Jubobs 1. Being on topic else where doesn't make it off topic here. 2. It sounds broken to me and broken code is specifically off topic on CR.

Comment: @RubberDuck I'm not suggesting a migration to CR at all; however, the wording of the question ( "*Is there a way to simplify [...]*") definitely suggest that this is a code-review question, and therefore, not a good fit for SO. But do what you think is best.

Comment: @Jubobs as it is, I don't think it's a good fit for either site.

Comment: @RubberDuck We're on the same page, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, here's the more efficient version (thanks to Evulse):

```
{% assign sort_array = "" %}

{% for line_item in cart.items %}
    {% for tag in line_item.product.tags %} 
        {% if tag == 'Tag I want second' %}
            {% assign sort_array = sort_array | append: 'B:' | append: line_item.id | append: ',' %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if tag == 'Tag I want First' %}
            {% assign sort_array = sort_array | append: 'A:' | append: line_item.id | append: ',' %}
        {% endif %}  
        {% if tag == 'Tag I want Third' %}
            {% assign sort_array = sort_array | append: 'C:' | append: line_item.id | append: ',' %}
        {% endif %} 
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% assign sort_array = sort_array | split: ',' | sort %}

{% for prefixed_line_item_id in sort_array %}
    {% for line_item in cart.items %}
        {% capture line_item_string %}{{line_item.id}}{% endcapture %}
        {% assign line_item_id = prefixed_line_item_id | split: ':' | last %}
        {% if line_item_id == line_item_string %} 
            {{line_item.product.title}}
        {%endif%}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```